# Guardar instancia de classe

Tags: php

Sou nova na programação, mas eu tenho um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver.

Como eu faço no PHP para salvar uma instância de uma classe?
Porque atualmente eu instancio uma classe e depois que o script para de executar, tudo que eu atribui é perdido. E eu tenho que instanciar de novo.

Exemplo de classe:

```
<?php

     class Usuario{
        private $nome;
        private $idade;
        // ... outros atributos

        public function CalcularSalario(){
           //Realizar calculo complexo com base nas informações salvar na classe
        }

     }
```

Assim toda vez eu preciso buscar os dados do usuário no banco e realizar um calculo de salario "complexo". Mas se eu já tivesse em algum lugar, eu apenas recuperaria a classe e caso haja alguma alteração no usuário, apenas setaria os valores e mandava calcular de novo.

Comment: Depende do que você quer fazer. Provavelmente deveria ter uma tabela com esses dados que são sempre calculados, ou modificar a tabela existente para mantê-los ali.

Comment: @Maniero vou dar um exemplo, Salario Base de 3 mil, tenho que tirar INSS, IR, se tiver aux. educação, adiciona metade do valor que o usuario gasta de educação, se tiver aux. medico, cobra uma taxa que depende da idade é mais cara. etc. Você acha que eu deveria ter isso em tabela?

Comment: Não sei, impede do cálculo, depende da sua necessidade de arquitetura. Claro que se o cálculo complexo é esse, nem sei se deveria. Alias se a preocupação é performance PHP é a linguagem errada. Não tem como eu dizer o que fazer sem entender o problema por completo.

Comment: @Maniero Coordenador entra no sistema, seleciona um usuário e pode adicionar/remover benefícios, aumentar salario, trocar cargo etc. Minha idéia era que somente na primeira vez trouxesse tudo do banco de dados e instanciasse em uma classe. Quando salvar o que precisa, recupera a classe e altera os valores que foram alterados na tela. Manda recalcular e manda salvar no banco. Assim eu não precisaria recuperar tudo novamente toda alteração em tela.

Comment: Como o sistema é web, não sei se isso seria possível.

Comment: Você está falando do fluxo do trabalho não da arquitetura, esta é uma decisão arquitetural. De qualquer forma, realmente web não é o ideal para fazer isto. Quase sempre a opção pela web é errada, mas pegou moda... Web és *stateless*, não é adequada para este tipo de aplicação, e o grosso das aplicações exigem *statefullness*, a maioria das pessoas não entendem isso. Então pra mim a solução é calcular de novo todas as vezes ou manter uma tabela com os dados. Claro é possível usar alguma forma intermediária, como um DB estilo NoSQL, mas acho que complicado a infra para pouco ganho, e mais...

Comment: ... pra consertar o erro feito por decidir fazer para web algo que não deveria ser.

Comment: "atualmente eu instancio uma classe e depois que o script para de executar, tudo que eu atribui é perdido. E eu tenho que instanciar de novo." - Essa conclusão é uma pérola. Já está melhor que a maior parte dos "programadores"  PHP, que não entendem isso, e você tem toda a razão de ter identificado o problema, pois ele é real. Esta é uma das maiores razões de OO em PHP ser na maioria dos casos uma grande perda de tempo. Perde quase todo o sentido OO numa aplicação sem estado.

Comment: @Bacco bem dito, OOP é sobre o gerenciamento do estado, em uma aplicação que perde o estado serve várias abordagens menos a orientada a objeto. Já perdi as esperanças que as pessoas vão aprender isso.